# Add text inside select tag next to the value

Tags: html, html-select

I would like to know how to add a text next to a value inside ? Do I have to use CSS for this?

I'm not really sure how to specify the question, hopefully someone will understand from the pictures!

How the select looks per default

[image: How the select looks per default]

How it looks when choosing a value

[image: How it looks when choosing a value]

Edit:

I don't have the actual code for this example, so I'm starting from scratch with:

```
    <strong>I represent:</strong>
    <select name="select">
        <option value="media">Media</option>
        <option value="travel-trade">Travel Trade</option>
        <option value="congress-org">Congress organization</option>
        <option value="cityhelsinki">City of Helsinki</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
     </select>
```

So I would like the "I represent:" text inside the select

Comment: Please edit your question to include the html or javascript you have tried so far.
See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems you only added samples of how it is looking now. Please give a graphic sample of how you want it to look. Next, please also show what you tried so far (HTML / CSS / Javascript), this site serves to improve your own efforts but you did not show any of your efforts.

Comment: Do you want every option say I represent: Media, etc. ?

Comment: I edited my question now (this is the first time I'm asking something here so I'm sorry for the lack of information)

Answer (score 0):

Add label infront of the select and style it with css to look like you want to.
If you want it inside the select you can add it to every option.